MedianBlur gives error when I put it in another function
I am doing image processing with cv2 in python.
Here is my code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

def use_clahe(l_channel, cliplimit):
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=cliplimit)
    cla = clahe.apply(l_channel)
    return cla

def improve_lightness(image, clahe_cliplimit):
    lab = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)
    cla = use_clahe(l, clahe_cliplimit)
    merged = cv2.merge((cla, a, b))
    bgr = cv2.cvtColor(merged, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
    return bgr

def background_detection(image):
    im32 = image * np.float32(1/255)
    background = cv2.medianBlur(im32, 31) * np.float32(1/255)
    background = cv2.stackBlur(background, (11, 11))
    blurred = im32
    blurred = cv2.medianBlur(blurred, 5)
    blurred = cv2.stackBlur(blurred, ksize=(5, 5))
    diff = blurred - background
    diff /= diff.std()
    mask = np.abs(diff) > 5
    mask = mask.any(axis=-1)
    mask = (mask*1).astype(np.uint8)
    return mask

def process_image(image):
    improved_exposure = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=1, beta=20)
    lab = cv2.cvtColor(improved_exposure, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)
    cla = use_clahe(l, 3)
    merged = cv2.merge((cla, a, b))
    bgr = cv2.cvtColor(merged, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
    im32 = bgr * np.float32(1/255)
    background = cv2.medianBlur(bgr, 31) * np.float32(1/255)
    background = cv2.stackBlur(background, (11, 11))
    blurred = im32
    blurred = cv2.medianBlur(blurred, 5)
    blurred = cv2.stackBlur(blurred, ksize=(5, 5))
    diff = blurred - background
    diff /= diff.std()
    mask = np.abs(diff) > 5
    mask = mask.any(axis=-1)
    mask = (mask*1).astype(np.uint8)
    return mask

def use_subprocesses(image):
    improved_exposure = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=1, beta=20)
    bgr = improve_lightness(improved_exposure, 3)
    mask = background_detection(bgr)
    return mask

def main():
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
    image = cv2.imread(filepath)
    process = process_image(image)
    # subprocess = use_subprocesses(image)
    cv2.imshow("Process", process)
    # cv2.imshow("Subprocess", subprocess)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

main()

Function process_image() works just as I want it to work, but if I try to use the use_subprocesses()-function, I get this strange error:
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/median_blur.simd.hpp:880: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.depth() == CV_8U && (cn == 1 || cn == 3 || cn == 4) in function 'cv::opt_AVX2::medianBlur'

The only difference in the codes is that use_subprocesses()-function has divided parts of the code into a few functions, whereas process_image()-function has all steps in one function. I have checked the datatypes with print(im32.dtype) etc... and the data types are the same in both cases. I don't understand why one solution gives error and the other doesn't, when there is absolutely no difference in the codes.
Can someone explain what's happening?

your im32 image in background_detection is of type float32 while the bgr image inside the function process_image is of type uint8.
you need to convert the im32 to uint8 in order for the cv2.medianBlur to work.
something like
background = cv2.medianBlur(np.uint8(im32), 31) * np.float32(1/255)

should work
